# How to store entire source of xml file as a string in c++

Tags: c++, xml, string, visual-c++, xml-parsing

The xml can only be referred to in the code as an external link for eg. "www.etc.com". I want to be able to extract certain words from the page source of certain websites, but first i need to dump the source content into a string or CString. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to fetch data from the internet.
I found [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/36638/) thread and some [source code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) regarding this.

Comment: That looks like HTML to me, but I need to extract xml source code

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if it's XML or HTML, you get text from the internet in the same way. libcurl is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DOM or SAX parser to retrieve each element.

If you want the entire xml file content in memory, then here is the sample code to make it

```
 

       ifstream fin("books.xml");

       if ( fin.fail())
          return 1;

       fin.seekg(0, ios::end);
       size_t length = fin.tellg();
       fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);

       char* buffer = new char[length+1];
       fin.read(buffer, length);
       buffer[length] = '\0';

       fin.close();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly then no, I don't want to get the content from my harddrive, but the internet...

Comment: If only there was a way to download the webpage first (the same way a browser does) but in my own c++ code.