# How do I download xml from the internet in C++

Tags: c++, html, xml, visual-c++, xml-parsing

The same way an internet browser does it when you save page as .xml, or view page source. Of course I am targeting a webpage that is in xml and starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Why do I want to do this? Well I want to dump the entire source of certain webpages into a string or CString, which I'm still [figuring out how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734371/how-to-store-entire-source-of-xml-file-as-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Check out [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: How is this question not an exact duplicate of the other question?

Comment: You've asked the same question twice, you get the same good answer 'use libcurl'. Libcurl will do what you want it to do, XML or HTML it makes no difference. There isn't much point in posting to a forum if you're not prepared to believe the answers you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned Visual C++, a good solution would be to make use of the recently published HTTP Casablanca library from Microsoft Research, provided you are able to use C++11 as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx

The you need to make use of a HTTP client, similar to what is described in this tutorial,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/devlabs/hh977106.aspx

Which can be something like,

```
http_client client( L"http://somewebsite.com" );

client.request( methods::GET, L"page-to-download.html" )
    .then( []( http_response response ) {
        cout << "HTML SOURCE:" << endl << response.to_string() << endl; })
    .wait();
```

Comment: This is so much better than libcurl, I really hope the standard gets something like this soon.

Answer (score 1):

Using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/):

```
size_t AppendDataToStringCurlCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *vstring)
{
    std::string * pstring = (std::string*)vstring;
    pstring->append((char*)ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

std::string DownloadUrlAsString(const std::string & url)
{
    std::string body;

    CURL *curl_handle;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, AppendDataToStringCurlCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &body);
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle); 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

    return body;
}
```