# Read xml lines from url

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, datetime, mfc

I want to read xml lines from an internet url( url will be input)  and extract the date value( dd,mm,yyyy) to a string or int. How can I do that using visual c++,mfc in an efficient way ?

The lines available on the web page are as shown below.

thanks.

```
<location>
<latitude>0</latitude>
<longitude>0</longitude>
</location>
<offset>0</offset>
<suffix>Z</suffix>
<localtime>11 Nov 2013 15:23:58</localtime>
<isotime>2013-11-11 15:23:58 +0000</isotime>
<utctime>2013-11-11 15:23:58</utctime>
<dst>False</dst>
```

Comment: The first question is: "How to open a file stored on an URL?" Low-level, using TCP connections, High-level, using class libraries such as cURL.

Comment: @  M M, thanks since I am not familiar with the process, honestly I dont know where to begin

Comment: Construct an XML Document object, load the url in the object (Load(url) method) and use SelectSingleNode or SelectNodes to query the data

Comment: No-one does this from scratch. It's a matter of choosing the right libraries for you. You need an XML processing library and a URL reading library (or maybe one that does both). Do some research.

Comment: thanks @ Marvin Smit, do you suggest any resources to look at or code for example ?

Comment: @  john, I am trying but any hint would be great

Comment: @user2937812 It's very hard to advise because there are so may variables. What O/S are you using? What compiler are you using? What are you licensing requirements? Do you want basic and simple, or complex and high powered? Do you require the libraries source code? What's good for me might not be good for you. But cURL (already mentioned) is good for reading from the internet. and Xerces is good for manipulating XML. Whether they are suitable for you though I cannot say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your all comments. I searched and used cURL library to overcome my issue.Possibly the easiest way with some examples. Also thanks to previous topic, it helped a lot: [How do I download xml from the internet in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736170/how-do-i-download-xml-from-the-internet-in-c)

```
  size_t AppendDataToStringCurlCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void        *vstring)
 {
std::string * pstring = (std::string*)vstring;
pstring->append((char*)ptr, size * nmemb);
return size * nmemb;
 }

 std::string DownloadUrlAsString(const std::string & url)
 {
std::string body;

CURL *curl_handle;
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, AppendDataToStringCurlCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &body);
curl_easy_perform(curl_handle); 
curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

return body;
 }

 int main(void)
  {
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string data_to_read;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.earthtools.org/timezone/0/0");

    data_to_read=DownloadUrlAsString("www.earthtools.org/timezone/0/0");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    // always cleanup 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

std::string str=data_to_read;
std::string str2 ("<utctime>");


std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
if (found!=std::string::npos)
std::cout << "first data found at: " << found << '\n';
//data_to_read[found+9]


char year[4];//="yyyy";
char month[2];//="mm";
char day[2];//="dd";

int delta=0;
int start=found+9;
for (int k=start; k<start+10;k++)
{
    if(k<start+4){
        year[delta]= data_to_read[k];
        delta++;
    }
    else if (k==start+4)
        delta=0;
    else if ((k>=start+5) && (k<=start+6))
    {
        month[delta]=data_to_read[k];
        delta++;
    }
    else if (k==start+7)
        delta=0;
    else if ((k>=start+8) && (k<=start+9))
    {
        day[delta]=data_to_read[k];
        delta++;
    }


}


int year_m=atoi(year);
int month_m=atoi(month);
int day_m=atoi(day);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`IXMLHTTPRequest` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148.aspx) to download the content.
- Once downloaded, the object's [`responseXML` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757066.aspx) returns [`IXMLDOMDocument` pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987.aspx) representing the parsed XML document.
- Use its `selectNodes` or `selectSingleNode` methods to locate the desired node, as represented by `IXMLDOMNode` interface.
- Read its `nodeValue` property to get the text it contains.

`InternetTimeToSystemTime` could be used to parse the string like "11 Nov 2013 15:23:58". I can't think, off the top of my head, of a ready-made function to parse an ISO date like "2013-11-11 15:23:58", but it seems amenable to a plain old `sscanf`.