# C++ Download XML file

Tags: c++, xml

Can you tell me how can I download an XML file from URL? Everyone in the forum says to use libcurl or other libraries like this. The problem is that I don't know how to use them. Can you please show me the best way to download XML file using C++? I want to use it in my small program which I made just for practice.

Comment: By means of c++ standard libraries its not possible. You'll have to use some 3rd party libraries to open a HTTP connection and to parse the XML text. There's a number of libraries that support doing this.

Comment: LibCurl has an entire page dedicated to small and simple examples: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Comment: Yes, I know. I read in other topics that I need to use for example libcurl, but the problem is that I can't find a good source to learn how to use it.

Comment: Can I use LibCurl with C++? Or it is only C library?

Comment: You can use it in C++.

Comment: @user3038079 Libcurl is a c library. You can use any c library with c++. May be a good advice is, wrapping access to c APIs to a small layer of your own c++ classes.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question posted here on SO: [Download file using libcurl in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636333/download-file-using-libcurl-in-c-c)

Comment: You may find this useful too: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/70568/)

Comment: I downloaded the LibCurl files from it's site. Now I'm trying to run the sample code given in the examples. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html
I connected the directory where the files are located with my VS2010 Project. Now I get this error and four more like it while compiling: 
**LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main**
Do you know what should I do to make the code run?

Comment: Did you download libraries as well as sample code?

Comment: I downloaded libraries and include files. I connected the include files in my projects properties. However I didn't connect the library files. Now I'm searching that option. If you can help me it will be awesome.

Comment: Well, I have a folder named "lib". But there are files with extension **.A** Are they valid library files? I think the sould be **.dll** or **lib**

Comment: .a is a unix/linux extension; you're right that you need .dll or .lib files.  Make sure you download a distribution that is appropriate to Windows.  I haven't worked with Visual Studio in awhile, so I don't have advice on how to specify additional libraries for a project.

Answer (score 1):

- **To download XML files from an URL in C++** (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736170/how-do-i-download-xml-from-the-internet-in-c)):

  > A good solution would be to make use of the recently published HTTP Casablanca library from Microsoft Research, provided you are able to use C++11 as well.
  >
  > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx
  >
  > The you need to make use of a HTTP client, similar to what is described in this tutorial,
  >   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/devlabs/hh977106.aspx
  >
  > Which can be something like,

  ```
  http_client client( L"http://somewebsite.com" );

  client.request( methods::GET, L"page-to-download.html" )
      .then( []( http_response response ) {
          cout << "HTML SOURCE:" << endl << response.to_string() << endl; })
      .wait();
  ```
- **To load XML in C++:**

Besides `LibCurl` you mentioned, I also recommend you to use **`MSXML`** to read/write xml files. Moreover, `MSXML` is proprietary by Microsoft (built within Windows) and support Windows x32/x64 applications. You don't need to install anything to use it.

For code examples, you can check out [one of my blog-post](http://herohuyongtao.blogspot.hk/2012/07/using-msxml-to-readwrite-xml-files.html) on how to use it in C++.

Comment: Thanks. But can you tell me what exactly I need to run this code? I guess I need to download the SDK and install it. Then what? Should I include a header or something in my code?

Comment: @user3038079 For the first part. You can download and run it under Visual Studio.